# Web3J quorum RawTransaction

Tags: java, blockchain, ethereum, quorum

I want to create a `RawTransaction` using quorum but it needs `Credential` object in the constructor. What's the equivalent of `Credential` in `RawTransaction`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this capability is not currently supported in Quorum if you require transaction privacy. If you don't want transaction privacy you can the standard web3j library.

For background as to where this is currently, please refer to the discussion on the following pull request https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/pull/146.

Answer (score 0):

you can perform `RawTransaction` either by creating new user and with account key or by coinbase account. for quorum, first of all, you need to set up nodes in the network.
the way you can setup node(n) in the network is given in this repo. https://github.com/ConsenSys/quorum-docker-Nnodes